# How to remove multiple java version from mac OS Big Sur?

Tags: java, java-8, terminal, macos-big-sur

**When i hit this command** `/usr/libexec/java_home -V` **i found two java version in my mac** **terminal:**

```
Matching Java Virtual Machines (2):

15.0.1 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "OpenJDK 15.0.1" /Users/xyz/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-15.0.1/Contents/Home
1.8.0_281 (x86_64) "Oracle Corporation" - "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_281.jdk/Contents/Home

/Users/xyz/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-15.0.1/Contents/Home
```

**I want to remove `openjdk 15.0.1` i have tried some solution from internet but nothing is working.** **Any help will be appreciated.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To uninstall Java, you must have administrator privileges and execute the remove command either as root or by using the sudo command

Then run:

```
sudo rm -rf /Users/xyz/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-15.0.1
```